# when I was plotting imported excel file in python, the xticks are overlapping and gathering on the left. How can I solve that?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, spyder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0e2p.png)when I was plotting imported excel file in python, the xticks are overlapping and gathering on the left.
How can I solve that?

Those are code snippets:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

plt.style.use('ggplot')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
data = pd.read_excel('Sample_data_xls.xls')

states_list1 = ["AK", "AR", "CO", "DE", "GA", "IA", "IN", "LA", "MD", "MI", "MS", "ND", "NH", "NM", 
                "OH", "PA", "SC", "TN", "VA", "WI", "WY"]


plt.figure()
plt.plot(data['gdp_growth_2009'], '--', color='red')
plt.plot(data['gdp_growth_2010'], 'b')
plt.plot(data['gdp_growth_2012'], 'g')
plt.ylabel('Growth Rates')
plt.xlabel('States')
plt.title('Growth Rates in 2009 and 2010')

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(25))
ax.axhline(y=0, color="black", alpha= 0.3)
plt.xticks(range(len(states_list1)), list(states_list1))

red_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='red', markersize=15, label='2009', linestyle='--')
blue_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='blue', markersize=15, label='2010')
green_line = mlines.Line2D([],[], color='green', markersize=15, label='2012')
plt.legend(handles=[red_line, blue_line, green_line])
```

Comment: Can you add an image of the plot?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your comment. I added an image at the top.